# What is the grammatical rationale for placing phrases such as "elle aussi", "n'en déplaise à certains" before the first verb, not after?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, incises

I just said jokingly in conversation:

> J’en conviens. Mais je connais une certaine amie à moi qui, **elle aussi**, a mis l’éthique commerciale de côté plus d’une fois en cherchant à augmenter le bénéfice net.

Usually, you place an adverb or an adverbial phrase right after the first verb in a clause, not before it. In some instances, however, I notice certain phrases such as "elle aussi" tend to be placed right before the first verb, enclosed with a set of commas.

It is true that in the case of the "elle aussi", the word order could just as well be "qui a ***elle aussi*** mis" without commas, but as for the following instance, I can't imagine the phrase "n'en déplaise à certains" coming after the first verb "est".

> Le monde, **n'en déplaise à certains**, est toujours, et ce depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale, sous l'influence américaine.

I wonder what types of phrases should be placed before the first verb? Does the use of commas have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

En français, l'ordre des mots n'est pas strict.
Voir par exemple cette fameuse réplique du *Bourgeois Gentilhomme* :

```
On les peut mettre premièrement comme vous avez dit : 
"Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour". 
Ou bien : "D’amour mourir me font, belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux". 
Ou bien : "Vos yeux beaux d’amour me font, belle Marquise, mourir". 
Ou bien : "Mourir vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, d’amour me font". 
Ou bien : "Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d’amour."
```

Cependant, il est vrai qu'on rencontre rarement "Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d'amour", par exemple. Dès lors, les choix sont purement stylistiques, ce qui ne veut pas dire qu'ils ne s'expliquent pas.

Dans votre premier exemple, "elle aussi" est sujet du verbe avoir. En d'autres termes, nous pouvons couper la phrase en deux (version A):

> Mais je connais une certaine personne.
> Cette personne aussi [=elle aussi] a mis l’éthique commerciale de côté plus d’une fois en cherchant à augmenter le bénéfice net.

Ainsi le sujet occupe la place naturelle du sujet (juste avant le verbe).

Dans votre second exemple, quelles sont les autres possibilités ?

> N'en déplaise à certains, le monde est toujours, et ce depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale, sous l'influence américaine.
>
> Le monde est toujours, n'en déplaise à certains, et ce depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale, sous l'influence américaine.
>
> Le monde est toujours, et ce depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale, n'en déplaise à certains, sous l'influence américaine.
>
> Le monde est toujours, et ce depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale, sous l'influence américaine, n'en déplaise à certains.

Dans le premier cas, vous auriez posé la même question.
Dans le second et le troisième cas, la juxtaposition des deux compléments "depuis la Seconde Guerre mondiale" et "n'en déplaise à certains" alourdit la phrase et fait perdre le fil.
Dans le dernier cas, on insiste beaucoup moins sur le "n'en déplaise à certains".

Comment: Exactement, et j'ajouterai que les deux expressions sont du même ordre grammaticalement parlant mais fonctionne discursivement de manière différente.

Comment: Hi. What's there to apologise for? ;) I'd welcome any suggestions; after all, this is the very raison d'être of this site. Long-standing members are already accustomed to the consistently non-constructive manner in which the member Lambie behaves, and have already learnt to only take what he/she says with a grain of salt. So far, I have been observing, as a *third party*, other members getting involved with these futile discussions, but since he/she started to contaminate my comment sections, someone needed to spell this out once and for all. That was all. Anyway, enough of this!

Comment: Getting back to the topic at hand, I used the phrasing "***Je connais une certaine amie à moi qui ...***" as a joking, sarcastic remark. I remember my friend once saying to me jokingly: "***Je connais un certain collègue qui n'avait d'yeux que pour son propre travail. Et le voilà qui ...***" or something like this. By the phrase "un certain collègue", he was referring to me, not someone else. I'm curious about this uneasiness that you feel about that phrasing. I wonder what exactly makes it sound *off*?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Perhaps it could be another question? Because you are right: it is quite independent. Anyway, the thing is you can say "je ne connais pas ce collègue" while you cannot say "je ne connais pas cet ami". So it allows you to say "je connais un collègue" but not "je connais un ami". The idea of "connaître" is silently implied by the idea of "ami" but not by this of "collègue". Perhaps the same idea as in "je me lave les mains" whereas "*je me lave mes mains" is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, I see. So basically, some overlap between "connais" and "amie" is problematic, huh? My intention was to impart a sarcastic, ***impersonal*** flavour to the part "je connais ***une certaine amie à moi***" as if I and this friend of mine are not so close. In my mind, it was close to "je connais ***quelqu'un*** qui ...". Are you still against my original phrasing? I might make a new question out of this later. ;)

Comment: @Alone-zee: Yes, anyway I do not like "je connais une certaine amie" exactly for the reason you gave. It is like "*je me lave mes mains" : whatever the intent, it is not correct. If you want to emphasize it is **your** hands you are washing, you can say "je lave *mes* mains". I think if you say "j'ai une certaine amie", you get the effect you wanted without the weird phrasing. If you really want to emphasize more, you can introduce the idea of doubt where there is no doubt: "j'ai une certaine amie, qui pourrait bien...". But overemphasing may be counter-productive.